# while executing gpx file in curl it is saying lattitude is missing

Tags: java, curl, fleet

I am working on `HERE Telematics`. I am using

```
curl --request POST -H "Content-Type: application/binary" --data binary "@C:\Test\gpx.gpx" "https://rme.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?routemode=car&app_id={EbuEzCM30PVYLtSsdtOK}&app_code={atl-trn6cHEDADsbaK2bLQ}"
```

It is giving this error:

> curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
>       % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
>       Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left
>       Speed
>       100   127  100   121  100     6    143      7 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   150{"faultCode":"8aa3a04f-9c58-46ae-a027-f3d460ed1b43","responseCode":"400 Bad Request","message":"Column LATITUDE missing"}

I have tried different ways, but it's giving the same error.

```
curl --request POST -H "Content-Type: application/binary" --data binary "@C:\Test2\run.gpx" "https://rme.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?routemode=car&app_id={EbuEzCM30PVYLtSsdtOK}&app_code={atl-trn6cHEDADsbaK2bLQ}"
```

Please let me know how to execute this `gpx` file in curl.

Comment: Please use formatting to make your post easily readable

Comment: `--data binary` should be `--data-binary`. Currently `"@C:\Test2\run.gpx"` is parsed as an URL which leads to the error you're seeing.